# Deserialize JSON with dynamic property which contains an array to dictionary with generic class

Tags: c#, .net, json

having this JSON:

```
{
    "lb1": [
        {
            "ip": "10.110.2.3",
            "name": "server1",
            "enabled_state": "ENABLED"
        },
        {
            "ip": "10.110.0.1",
            "name": "server2",
            "enabled_state": "ENABLED"            
        }
    ]
    "lb2": [
        {
            "ip": "10.120.2.3",
            "name": "server3",
            "enabled_state": "ENABLED"
        }
    ]
}
```

where `lb1` and `lb2` are dynamic properties (values can be different) and I want to parse it to C# class `NetworkApiResult`
Following few SO links how to parse json with dynamic property I ended up with below try:

**NetworkApiResult:**

```
public class NetworkApiResult<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("")]
    public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>> Result { get; set; }
}
```

**NetowrkApiNode**

```
public class NetworkApiNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ip")]
    public string IpV4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("enabled_state")]
    public bool EnabledState { get; set; }
}
```

**How I fire and attempt to deserialize:**

```
ExtractResult<NetworkApiResult<NetworkApiNode>>(query, @"samplePayload");

private T ExtractResult<T>(string query, string jsonContent)
    {
        var response = _client.PostAsync(query, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        using (Stream s = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
    }
```

any idea what am I doing wrong here? `Result` property of `NetworkApiResult` is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Json shared, you need to Deserialize using

```
serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,List<NetworkApiNode>>>(reader);
```

You do **NOT** need the wrapping `NetworkApiResult<T>`.

However, please note you  also need a change in NetworkApiNode. The `"enabled_state"` is a String and not a boolean. If you need to convert the value to a boolean value, you could use a readonly property which checks the deserialized `State` for the value as seen in the code below.

```
public class NetworkApiNode
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ip")]
    public string IpV4 { get; set; }

    public bool EnabledState => State.Equals("ENABLED");

    [JsonProperty("enabled_state")]
    public string State{get;set;}
}
```

Sample Output

[image]